# Distribution of determinants of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $\{0,1,\ldots,q-1\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, probability-distributions, determinant

> Consider the set $M(n,q)$ of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $\{0,1,\ldots,q-1\}$, where $q$ is a prime power. What can be said about the distribution of the determinant of matrices in $M(n,q)$? (A 'heuristic' statement of the problem: taking $\{0,1,\ldots,q-1\}$ as a basis for $F=\mathbb{Z}_q$, what do the determinants of matrices over $F$ look like if you don't mod out $q$?)

Obviously $|M(n,q)| = q^{n^2}$. Since $|GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)| = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} q^n-q^k$, in $\mathbb{F}_q$ we get a clean answer for how many are divisible by $q$: the values are equally distributed (modulo $q$, there are $\frac{1}{q-1}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} q^n-q^k$ matrices with determinant $j$, $1\le j\le q-1$). But if we do not look mod $q$, as it were, the question becomes substantially more difficult; to be frank, I'm not sure where to start or if there are any clear patterns. Information about the limiting behavior or any upper bounds on the magnitude of the determinant would be welcome as well.

I computed the distributions for several values of $n=2,3$ and $2\le q\le 5$; the plot labels are of the form $\{n,q\}$.

[image]

As expected, determinant zero is the most common option and a determinant of $a$ is just as likely as a determinant of $-a$. Past that, I admit I'm a little out of my league, but it seems like an interesting problem.

Comment: I tried to get pictures for more values of $q,n$ but it took a very long time (computing determinants of $q^{n^2}$ $n\times n$ matrices will do that...). Might update the picture if the command ever finishes compiling.

Comment: this might not be relevant to your question, but if you normalize the determinant by dividing by $q^n$, you should get a limiting distribution as $q \to \infty$ for fixed $n$, and the limiting distribution should be the distribution of the determinant for $n$ i.i.d. vectors chosen uniformly from $[0, 1]^n$

Comment: This doesn't answer the question quite, but the following springs to mind: viewing entries in $(\mathbb{Z}_{< q})^{n^2}$ then matrices with a fixed determinant $D$ lie on a Zariski closed subset (cut out by the determinant polynomial) so the density tends to $0$ as $q \to \infty$. In particular singular matrices have density $0$. To get a more precise result you could use that the determinant is homogeneous degree $n$ in the variables

Comment: I remember someone posted a question about determinant distribution of $2\times2$ matrices, that also looked like a Gaussian curve, I'll link it soon.

Comment: [The question was deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816316/distribution-of-determinant-of-random-2-times-2-matrices).

Comment: "If we consider these determinants modulo $$" — that's not how $\mathbb{F}_q$ works, unless $q$ is a prime.

Comment: @MigMit I know, it's only a heuristic.

Comment: Even the question of finding the maximum determinant of an $n\times n$ zero-one matrix is not completely solved.

Comment: See, e.g., http://oeis.org/A003432

Answer (score 5):

In the continuous limit of $n$ fixed, $q \to \infty$, $\frac{1}{q^n}\log |\det(M)|$ is asymptotically normal as $n \to \infty$. See Terry Tao's comments on [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13008/expected-determinant-of-a-random-nxn-matrix). The [linked paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.0752.pdf) of Nguyen--Vu has a nicely readable intro, see particularly around equations (1.6)-(1.7). The intuition is *roughly* that the determinant is going to be the (signed) hypervolume, which can be computed as an iterated multidimensional "base times height". Taking the logarithm and fuzzing your eyes, this looks like a sum of i.i.d. random variables. The details are involved, of course, and I have not attempted to digest them. Someone with expertise in this approach may be able to "discretize" it quickly. It's likely more appropriate as an MO question than an MSE question.

Edit: Now that I look at it, Nguyen--Vu's actual main Theorem 1.1 covers this discrete case too (even though the linked MO thread was just after the continuous case), and more generally any distribution with exponentially decaying tails. So, we get that for fixed $q$, $\log |\det(M)|$ is asymptotically normal as $n \to \infty$, with explicit convergence rates.

Comment: Should be $\log |\det(M)|$ yes? PS, hi Josh!

Comment: @JairTaylor Fixed, thanks! To be clear, it's not important since $\det(M)$ is symmetric about 0. Nguyen--Vu do have to fiddle a bit with the density of 0. (Hope you've been well!)

Comment: Thank you for the research and exposition; if nothing changes, this answer will probably earn the bounty. Closing my eyes a bit and looking at the graphs I included makes me buy the asymptotic distribution is normal (although a particular distribution, say for fixed $q$ and varying $n$, seems much more subtle) and I'm grateful for the means to confirm this.